# six.b(literal) same as b'literal'? Python 2/3

Tags: python

I have a piece of code, are these two equivalent? I understand that `six` module is used for making code compatible with both 2 and 3.

```
from six import b
os.write(w, b("EMount unsuccessful"))

os.write(w, b"EMount unsuccessful")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the python version you are using.
In 2.6 or higher, those are equivalent and you can use u instead of u().

Comment: I do not support anything before 2.7 so the answer is basically its same.

Comment: In that case it is